# SendMessage only send the *first* character of the string

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, sendmessage

I am using the following python code to send String to a RAD Studio C++ Builder built application:

```
import win32con
import win32gui
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes  

FindWindow = win32gui.FindWindow
SendMessage = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW

class COPYDATASTRUCT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dwData', ctypes.wintypes.LPARAM),
        ('cbData', ctypes.wintypes.DWORD),
        ('lpData', ctypes.c_wchar_p) 
    ]

hwnd = FindWindow(None, "SIGNAL")
cds = COPYDATASTRUCT()
cds.dwData = 0

mystr = "This is a message to signal..."

cds.cbData = ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(mystr))
cds.lpData = ctypes.c_wchar_p(mystr)

SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_COPYDATA, 0, ctypes.byref(cds))
```

It is perfectly find the opponent application and SendMessage sends data.

**My problem:** It *only* sends the 1st character of the string. So instead of: `"This is a message to signal..."` , it only sends `"T"`.

I am sure that I am overlooking something trivial, but I could not found it.

Comment: Often caused by one end using Unicode (wide) characters and the other using multibyte characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support all may run into the same task/issue, the working "receive" code (RAD Studio C++ builder) is:

```
void __fastcall Tmain_form::WMCopyData(TMessage& Message)  // Receiving messages from Python script in C++ Builder
{
int DataSize;
wchar_t* Data;

COPYDATASTRUCT* CopyData = reinterpret_cast <COPYDATASTRUCT*> (Message.LParam);

    DataSize = CopyData->cbData;

    if (DataSize > 0)
    {
        Data = new wchar_t[DataSize];
        memcpy(Data, CopyData->lpData, DataSize);

        // Process your data....    
    
        delete [] Data;
    }
}
```

Just to be complete, this goes to the header file, below 'protected':

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_COPYDATA, TMessage, WMCopyData)
END_MESSAGE_MAP(TForm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your C++ code is interpreting the `cds.lpData` as a `char*` instead of as a `wchar_t*`, and likely is not paying attention to the byte count indicated by `cds.cbData`, either.

Also, the Python code should be setting `cds.lpData` to (a pointer to) the Unicode buffer you created from `mystr`, not (a pointer to) `mystr` itself.

Comment: THANK YOU ! It was exactly the case, how dummy I am to miss it. BIG BIG Thank you ! I was trying to push the vote button, but it say: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." So allow me to thank you here from the bottom of my heart, as I was overlooking this error in my code for 2 days now, so it was  huge help. Have a lovely day!